# Modal dialog all buttons exit and url line gets corrupted with last JASON response

Tags: javascript, html, events, modal-dialog

I have modified a W3 HTML example that displays modal dialogs, adding additional buttons to the first modal form. There are two methods to quit the modal by clicking on the background and by using the Quit button. The other buttons are for form functions and should not cause the form to close.
I have two issues:

1. all buttons cause the form to close - even though the execution does not flow to the code line that hides the modal form. something is incorrect with the

   ````
       if(event.target.className == "modal") {
         event.target.style.display = "none";
       }
   }```
   ````

handler that closes the form even if it does not go through the `if` condition.
2. On exit from the dialog using the Quit button the url line of the parent page gets updated to include the last JASON response from the server: *http://127.0.0.1:20080/?jason=%2Fapi%2Fcage%2Fpower&name=%7B+%22data%22%3A+%5B+%7B+%22status%22%3A+1+%7D%2C+%7B+%22status%22%3A+1+%7D+%5D+%7D* or is appended with http://127.0.0.1:20080/**?jason=&name=**
if there was no call to the server

I tried to debug the issues by stepping through the code but could not come up with the cause or fix both issues occur out of the script code, any help will be most appreciated.

My code:

```
<html>  <head>
    <title>Title of the document</title>
    <style> * {font-family: Arial !important;}</style>
    <style>
    .modal {
        display: none;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 8;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        overflow: auto;
        background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    }
    .modal-content {
        margin: 50px auto;
        border: 1px solid #999;
        width: 700px;
    }
    h2,p {
        margin: 0 0 20px;
        font-weight: 400;
        color: #000;
    }      
    span {
        color: #666;
        display: block;
        padding: 0 0 5px;
    }
    form {
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
        box-shadow: 0 2px 5px #f5f5f5;
        background: #fff;
    }
    input, textarea {
        width: 90%;
        padding: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        border: 1px solid #1c87c9;
        outline: none;
    }
    .contact-form button {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 10px;
        border: none;
        background: #09253d;
        font-size: 16px;
        font-weight: 400;
        color: #fff;
    }
    button:hover {
        background: #0A354d;
    }
    .close {
        color: #aaa;
        float: right;
        font-size: 28px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    .close:hover, .close:focus {
        color: black;
        text-decoration: none;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    button.modalButton {
        background: none;
        border-top: none;
        outline: none;
        border-right: none;
        border-left: none;
        border-bottom: #02274a 1px solid;
        padding: 0 0 3px 0;
        font-size: 16px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    button.modalButton:hover {
        border-bottom: #a99567 1px solid;
        color: #a99567;
    }
    .column {
        float: left;
        width: 200px;
        padding: 0px;
        height: 100px; 
    }
    .row:after {
        /* Clear floats after the columns */
        content: "";
        display: table;
        clear: both;
    }
    </style>
    <style> table, td { outline: 0;border: 1px solid #000; } </style> 
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>Multiple Popup Forms</h2>
    <p>
      <button id="module0" class="modalButton" data-modal="modalOne">Contact Us</button>
    </p>
    <p>
      <button id="module2" class="modalButton" data-modal="modalTwo">Send a Form</button>
    </p>
    <div id="modalOne" class="modal">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="contact-form">
          <!--a class="close">&times;</a-->
          <form action="/">
            <div class="row" float="left"  background="#fa7a25">     
                <div class="column"  style="width:30px; height:60px; background: #fa7a25">
                    <div class="column"  style="width:8px; margin-left:16px; margin-top:10px; height:36px; border:1px solid #000; background: #00dd00"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="column"  style="width:480px; height:60px; background: #fa7a25">
                    <div style="height:10px;"></div>
                    <a style="color:#fff; font-size: 18px;margin-left:8px; ">S/N: Serial Number line</a>
                    <p><a style="color:#fff; margin-left:8px;height:14px;"> information line</a></p>
                </div>
                <div class="column"  style="width:190px; height:60px; background: #eee"></div>
            </div>      
            <div class="row" float="left"  background="#fa7a25">     
                <div class="column"  style="width:510px; height:300px; background: #fff">
                    <div style="height:10px;"></div>
                    <div class="column" style="height:20px;margin-left:12px;width:100px;">
                        <b>Get REST:</b>      
                    </div>
                    <div class="column" style="height:30px;margin-left:12px;width:100px;">
                        <select id="jason" name="jason" onclick="myChange()">
                        <option></option>
                        <option>/api/cage</option>
                        <option>/api/cage/state</option>
                        <option>/api/cage/power</option>
                        <option>/api/cage/groups</option>
                        </select>                        
                    </div>
                    <div>
                      <input id="input1" style="margin-left:12px;" class="fname" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Full name">
                    </div>
                    <span style="margin-left:12px;">Message</span>
                    <div>
                      <textarea style="margin-left:12px;"rows="4"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="column"  style="width:190px; height:300px; background: #eee">
                    <button id="save-default" style="margin-top:12px;">Save as Default</button>
                    <button id="restore-factory" style="margin-top:30px;">Restore Factory</button>
                    <button id="quitButton" type="cancel" href="/" style="margin-top:80px;">Quit</button>
                </div>
            </div>      
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="modalTwo" class="modal">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="contact-form">
          <span class="close">&times;</span>
          <form action="/">
            <h2>My form</h2>
            <div>
              <input class="fname" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Full name">
              <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Email">
              <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Phone number">
            </div>
            <span>Message</span>
            <div>
              <textarea rows="4"></textarea>
            </div>
            <button id="quitButton" type="cancel" href="/">Quit</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
   <script>
    modalBtns = [...document.querySelectorAll(".modalButton")];
      
    modalBtns.forEach( function(btn) {
        
        // setup dialog opening buttons for the modal dialogs
        if (btn.getAttribute('data-modal')) {
            btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
                modal = btn.getAttribute('data-modal'); 
                
                if (modal) {        
                document.getElementById(modal).style.display = "block";
            }});
        }
        else if (btn.type == 'cancel') {
            btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
                
                // Form cancel button closes the dialog box
                if (btn.type == 'cancel') {
                    modal = btn.closest('.modal');
                    modal.style.display = "none";
//              console.log(window.location.href );
            }});
        }
    });
    
    window.onclick = function(event) {
        if(event.target.className == "modal") {
          event.target.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
    
    function myChange() {
            var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
            {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                    if (document.getElementById('jason').value == "/api/cage/state")
                        document.getElementById("input1").value = "State is: " + myObj.data;
                    else if (document.getElementById('jason').value == "/api/cage")
                        document.getElementById("input1").value = myObj.data.partNumber;
                    else 
                        document.getElementById("input1").value = this.responseText 
            }
        };
        xhttp.open("GET", document.getElementById('jason').value, true);
        xhttp.send();   
    }
    
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found after posting the questions that the HTML button has a default behavior which is set by the type property of the button. Left unset it defaults to submit which leaves the browser's JS to do its thing. to correct both issues I simply changed all buttons type to button.